# With SonicWall, cannot access URL inside network

Tags: networking, firewall, web-server, sonicwall

We have a website running on port 80 on our network. Port 80 is forwarded outside of the network, and it is accessible through a URL that points to the IP or the IP itself.

However, inside the network, it is not possible to access the external domain/IP address. It's possible to use the local I.P. address. For example, the web server can be accessed by using 192.168.168.22:80, but not mydomain.com. Mydomain.com works from an external network.

This is likely due to a rule in SonicWall. We are using Sonicwall TZ 215 and I am not sure what rules would allow for this access.

Let me know if I need to provide more information. Currently, there is a rule set from WAN to LAN to allow it to be accessed out of the network. I have tried some other rules, but have not found what works.

Answer (score 3):

You need what's commonly called a "hairpin NAT" rule.  You redirect internal users who are trying to reach the public IP back inside the network to the local IP.

In the sonicwall NAT rules, you'll need a rule like this:

```
Original Source              Translated Source       Original Destination      Translated Destination      Service
Local Subnets (or similar)   Original                <WAN IP of DNS entry>     <LAN IP of server>          Port 80
```

Something like this:
[image: Sonicwall Add NAT Rule]

Comment: Could you be more specific? I was unable to get this working.

Comment: Edited to include screenshot of NAT rule window.

Comment: I do not have 'Local Subnets' as a choice. Would this perhaps be 'LAN Subnets'?

Comment: Correct.  I was going from [poor] memory.

Comment: Web server is the address object of my web server. This doesn't seem to be working. Any ideas? http://i.imgur.com/cHzVLQQ.png

Comment: Ah, one more try -  change "Translated Source" to "WAN IP of mydomain.com".  Everything else looks good.